# How to open a document in 'current window' in office add-in instead of opening in a new window?

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm working on Office 365 Word [Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/word-add-ins-programming-overview?view=word-js-preview) that opens a document.

When we open the document via `context.application.createDocument(base64string).open()`, it launches a new window instead of opening the document in current browser tab (in case of web Add-in) or current instance of word (in case of windows Add-in).

Here is my use case:

1. Check if there is already an open document and ask the user to save or lose changes.
2. Have an API to close the current open document e.g. `context.document.close();`
3. Open a new document via `context.application.createDocument(base64string).open()`, so that the document is opened in the current window instead of opening in a new instance of word.

Is there any workaround to achieve this?

Cross posted [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom-mso_365hp/how-to-open-a-document-in-current-window-in-office/4cefc429-6565-4494-b694-6516aefd64ef?tm=1591818630051).

Thanks.

Comment: There is a workaround to open the document directly in the body of current document by replacing the current document (context.document.body.insertFileFromBase64(base64string, Word.InsertLocation.replace);), but it doesn't include headers, footers and sometimes the formatting is totally messed up.

Comment: Excellent! It's a great workaround! :):):)

Comment: I have the same question. And I have come up with exactly the same "workaround", but it's not really...satisfactory.